# Can I take a metal knife and fork through airport security?

Tags: airport-security

On my last flight I was served a meal with a metal knife and fork, which was a pleasant change compared to plastic utensils. This gave me the idea of packing my own utensils for the next flight as a small way of improving the economy experience.

However, would I be allowed to take a standard knife and fork through airport security? By 'standard' I'm referring to something like this:

[image]

To make the question less broad I'm restricting it to North American and European airports.

Comment: I tried to take the silverware I received on the airplane (Lufthansa) and got my butter knife confiscated in Minneapolis because it was serrated even though I got it from an airplane. I took this set of silverware from Kalispell mt to New York to Aruba and nothing happened. I was trying to be environmentally conscious. Wtf type of damage can someone do with a serrated reusable butter knife?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the US side, the TSA run a [website](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all), giving generic advice on whether items can taken as carry-on, in checked luggage, or not at all. Note the important disclaimer that **the final decision rests with the TSA officer on whether an item is allowed through the checkpoint**, but searching for "utensils" gives the response:

> **Carry On Bags: Yes**
>
> **Checked Bags: Yes**
>
> Knives, except for plastic or round-bladed butter knives, are not allowed in carry-on bags.

So, you're likely to be ok with the fork and the spoons, but the table knife is liable to be confiscated.

Comment: "round-bladed butter knives" seem to be the kind I want to take on board

Comment: I would be mightily surprised if you consistently got through with those. Don’t take your grandmother’s silverware if you’re not ready to abandon it at the security checkpoint...

Comment: @JonathanReez It'll depend on whether they mean the general meaning of any non-serrated table knife or the strict "this knife is only for butter" meaning!

Comment: I have had forks confiscated in Europe on two occasions. Both times I left one in my bag accidentally. It triggers an in depth bag search that can take a while. So I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: A true butter knife usually has a point on the end. Not very sharp, but a point nonetheless. https://www.libertytabletop.com/product/lexington-butter-knife/ What the TSA is referring to is probably a non-serrated dinner knife. https://www.americanhotel.com/walco-ultra-dinner-knife-stainless-steel-18-10/p/U8T9645